# Помогите исправить данный код

Tags: jquery, ajax

Имеется код для добавления данных из json в div блоки с одинаковым классом и с уникальным id. Но он не работает. В чем проблема?

```
$.ajax({
url: 'ajax/prop',
dataType: 'html',
success:function(data){
var jsonStr = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(jsonStr);
    $('.prop').each(function (index, element) {
          var container = $(this).attr('id');
          console.log(index, container);
     jsonStr.forEach(item => {
let innerHtml = '';
Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
innerHtml += `<dd>${item[key]}<dd> `;
});

let $btn = $('<button type="submit"></button>').
attr("id", "btn_" + item.id).addClass("btn btn-warning btn-md").html(innerHtml);
$("#prop_" + item.id).html($btn);
  });
    return false
 });
}
});

0: {id: "1", profit: "Продать"}
1: {id: "2", profit: "Продать"}
2: {id: "3", timeleft: "9 минут"}
3: {id: "4", timeleft: "2 часа 9 минут"}
4: {id: "5", timeleft: "5 часов 30 минут"}
5: {id: "9", profit: "Купить"}
6: {id: "11", timeleft: "23 часа 9 минут"}

0 "1"
1 "2"
2 "3"
3 "4"
4 "5"
5 "9"
6 "11"
```

Спасибо за помощь решил проблему, исправленный код в вопросе.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Уберите внешний цикл `$('.prop').each(...);`. Он не нужен.

Comment: @Igor подскажите а как сделать чтобы в кнопке показывались вторые значения без id?

Comment: @Артём Изменил код в ответе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#' + container).append(itemBtn);
```

Обратите внимание: выборка `$('#' + container)` содержит тот же самый элемент, что и `$(this)`. Если, конечно, на странице нет повторяющихся `id`.

---

*Совет дня:*

*Не смешивайте манипуляции с элементами DOM-дерева в чистом javascript-е, с аналогичными манипуляциями в jQuery.*

---

Хм, добавьте:

```
var jsonStr = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(jsonStr);
```

и

```
var container = $(this).attr('id');
console.log(index, container);
```

Что в консоли?

---

Я все понял. Когда Вы добавляете кнопки, Вы присваиваете им такие же `id`, как у элементов с классом `"prop"`. Поэтому селектор `$('#' + container)` находит не `div`, a `button`, добавленный в первый `div`. Визуально, это выглядит как если бы все было добавлено в первый `div`.

```js
var jsonStr = [
  { id: "1", profit: "Продать" },
  { id: "2", profit: "Продать" },
  { id: "3", timeleft: "9 минут" },
  { id: "4", timeleft: "2 часа 9 минут" },
  { id: "5", timeleft: "5 часов 30 минут" },
  { id: "9", profit: "Купить" },
  { id: "11", timeleft: "23 часа 9 минут" }
];

jsonStr.forEach(item => {
  let innerHtml = '';
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
    if (key != "id")
      innerHtml += `<dd>${item[key]}<dd> `;
  });

  let $btn = $("<button></button>").
    attr("id", "btn_" + item.id).addClass("btn").html(innerHtml);
  $("#prop_" + item.id).append($btn);
});
```

```css
.prop {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prop_1" class="prop"></div>
<div id="prop_2" class="prop"></div>
<div id="prop_3" class="prop"></div>
<div id="prop_11" class="prop"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло, но теперь проблема в том что все добавляется в первый блок!

Comment: @Артём Точно? Вообще-то, должно добавиться во все одно и то же.

Comment: Точно только в первый div

Comment: Решил перестановкой цикла $('.prop').each(function (index, element) {
         var container = $(this).attr('id');                          под.  jsonStr.forEach(function(item) {                   но добавляется как то по странному в первом div все значения , во втором 1 значение в третьем 3 значения и т.д.

Comment: Извиняюсь, в консоль посмотреть не могу, нет ПК рядом

Comment: @Артём Когда будет возможность, покажите текущий код, данные с сервера и `id` элементов в цикле.

Comment: код обновил, данные и id добавил

Comment: @Артём Посмотрите добавление к ответу.

Comment: Помогло, но как вы и говорили во все div добавляется одно и то же, почему так?

Comment: @Артём Потому что это именно то, что делает код в вопросе. Для каждого `div`-а Вы перебираете все элементы массива `jsonStr` и создаете столько же кнопок, сколько в массиве элементов. Посмотрите код в ответе.

Comment: а как сделать чтоб добавлялась только одна кнопка. Может нужно прерывать цикл?

Comment: @Артём Так, давайте разберемся. Вас устраивает то, что делает код в ответе? Что Вы вообще хотите сделать? Сколько кнопок должно быть создано в каждом `div.prop`? Соответствие между `div.prop` и элементами массива должно быть по `id`?

Comment: Почти устраивает хочу сделать по одной кнопке в каждом div. Кнопки уже соответствуют div, но их 7 штук